Filter JSON keys with wild card
I'm using NiFi for the first time.  I have the basics down, but I think I'm making the common error of thinking programmatically instead of set wise.
I'm given the following JSON:
{
  "ABC#01": 1.0,
  "ABC#02": 2.0,
  ...
  "ABC#nn": "zz.z",
  "AQB#01": "abc",
  "BRB": 123,
  ...
  "TTT#01": 1234567,
  "TTT#02": 23456789,
  ...
  "TTT#nn": zzzzzzz
}

I need to transform it into:
{
  "1234567": { //<= Acquired from the value of TTT#01
    "ABC#01": 1
  },
  "23456789": { //<== value of TTT#02
    "ABC#02": 2
  }, 
  { 
   ...
  }  
}

Where I also discard all of the key/values not involved.  IE: "AQB#01": "abc", "BRB": 123, There are an unknown number of entries.  The only thing I'm told is true is that ABC#nn = TTT#nn.  NN can be any value and there can be any number of other values to discard.
Any suggestions?

You can match by
"*" wildcard (to make the LHS looping) vs.
&(1,1) representation(in order to bring the 1st occurrence of asterisk from 1 upper level)
and combine all stuff under common object nodes with keys of "01", "02", ... "nn"
within the following transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "TTT\\#*": { "@": "&(1,1).key" },//double backslashes are used to escape special character #
      "ABC\\#*": { "@": "&(1,1).value.&" }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { "@value": "@key" }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Great answer.  Thank you

No worries @JimF  nice to help

one small problem.  How do I change the TTT#01 with it's value?  IE: "1234567": { "ABC#01": 1.0 }  Thanks!

Oh sorry, I missed that, ust fixed it now @JimF
